# snapcraft with different ROS_MASTER_URI

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to set a different ROS_MASTER_URI for my snap.

My package is very simple. Only have one launch file to lauch usb-cam package.
My problem is that, I can not change the MASTER_URI when running the snap.
Here is my snapcraft.yaml file

```
parts:
  workspace:    
    plugin: catkin
    rosdistro: lunar
    catkin-packages: [main_launch]

apps:
  usbcam:
    command: export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.28:11311/ roslaunch main_launch usb_cam_launch.launch 
    plugs: [network, network-bind]
```

But I got this:

```
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [4297]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
```

EDITS:
My bashrc file already set MASTER_URI, but it does not affect snap:

```
export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.0.6
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.28:11311/
source /opt/ros/lunar/setup.bash
source ~/Workspace/devel/setup.bash
```

Furthermore, how can I pass arguments to my snap command.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/277607/snapcraft-with-different-ros_master_uri/) by [Chuong Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23343/chuong-nguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2017-12-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-08**:
I don't know anything about snap, but if the `command` section is essentially run in a `bash` session, then I believe the command line should be

```
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://.. roslaunch ..
```

you can set env vars for a specific invocation with `bash`, but then you don't use `export`.

**Comment by [Chuong Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23343/chuong-nguyen/) on 2017-12-08**:
Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, without export, snap throws an error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ~/workspace/prime/ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.28:11311/'

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-09**:
Again: not a snap expert, but you could probably get around this by writing a small wrapper (bash) script that sets the env var and then starts your `roslaunch ..` command.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-09**:
Other than that I think this is not a ROS questions, but a snapcraft one. I advise you to ask this on a more appropriate forum, such as Ubuntu's [snapcraft forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-12-09**:
If you do post there, could I ask you to please comment here with a link to your snapcraft forum post? That way we keep things connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks gvdhoorn for your suggestion. I repost the question in snapcraft forum at
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-to-set-ros-master-uri-with-snapcraft/3115?u=chuong98

The solution is to add

```
catkin-ros-master-uri: http://192.168.0.28:11311
```

---

Originally posted by [Chuong Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/23343/chuong-nguyen/) with karma: 136 on 2017-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1